# Ошибка при AJAX запросе

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, cors

Наткнулась на одну проблему при AJAX запросе на https://newsapi.org/ сервер. Написала такой код:

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=8f76000c70ba44faa4ff2deae9818fe7');
    xhr.addEventListener('load', (e) =>{
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        // console.log(response);
        cb(response);
    })

    xhr.addEventListener('error', (e) =>{
        console.log('Error');
    })
    xhr.send();
}

getPosts(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

Но в консоли выходит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста помогите!!! Как решить эту проблему? Другие сервера новостных API не нашла(

Comment: http://g.zeos.in/?q=blocked%20by%20cors%20policy%20javascript

Answer (score 0):

В целях безопасности современные браузеры блокируют запросы AJAX к доменам, отличным от того, с которого загружен скрипт. Т.е. кроме своего "родного". Делать такие запросы можно только если удаленный сервер разрешает это делать, устанавливая заголвоок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Данный сервер просто этого не сделал.

Посмотрите https://open-platform.theguardian.com/documentation/ с ним таких проблем быть не  должно.